# Return strings from c function in Golang

Tags: c, string, go, cgo

I am trying to a call *C* function in *GO*. This works to some extends (for integers). However, there are issues
A minimal example is given below

```
package main

/*
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_reverse(char* src, int len, char *dst){
  dst = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
  printf("[c-part] src=%s\n", src);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    dst[i] = src[len - 1 - i];
  }
  dst[len] = 0;
  printf("[c-part] dst=%s\n", dst);
}

void some_text(char* buffer, unsigned long long int *year){
  buffer = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
  sscanf("year 2018d", "%s %16llu", buffer, year);
  printf("will return (%s, %16llu)\n", buffer, *year);

}
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"
import "fmt"

func Reverse(a string) (dst string) {

    c_src := C.CString(a)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c_src))
    c_len := C.int(len(a))
    c_dst := C.CString(dst)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c_dst))

    C.my_reverse(c_src, c_len, c_dst)

    return string(*c_dst)

}

func Sometext() (dst string, year int64) {

    c_dst := C.CString("")
    c_year := C.ulonglong(0)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c_dst))

    C.some_text(c_dst, &c_year)

    return string(*c_dst), int64(c_year)

}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("[gopart] dst=%v\n\n\n", Reverse("Hello World"))

    buf, year := Sometext()
    fmt.Printf("received (%v, %v)\n", buf, year)
}
```

These are two c-function, which allocate a new buffer in c. 
However, I get the output

```
[c-part] src=Hello World
[c-part] dst=dlroW olleH
[gopart] dst=


will return (year,             2018)
received (, 2018)
```

This means, these strings are available in C.But I can never use these strings in GO afterwards.
Does the Go-Garbage collector remove the string before I can use it?

I expect to see

```
[gopart] dst=dlroW olleH
received (year, 2018)
```

there as well.

Comment: This is kind of a confused example. You don't need to allocate C strings in Go if you're only going to go and allocate the again in C. Your output parameters also need to be a pointer to what you want you want to replace, i.e. `char** buffer`.

Comment: This would be really strange with `char**`. How can I wrap standard functions like `char * strcpy(char *dest, char *src);`? I am sure the c-function have the correct signatures (without thinking of golang).

Comment: Well `strcpy` doesn’t allocate itself, while your functions do. If you want to work like that, then allocate the correct buffer size before hand and reuse it.

Comment: I see, you're right! Although, it does not answer the question. If there would be not enough buffer, the app wouldcrash, right? But I just get "".

Comment: @leafbebop nope that's not it.

Comment: @wieschoo: no the app might not crash, because C is not a memory-safe language like Go, and has no automatic bounds checking. You are free to corrupt your own program's memory however you want.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to handle memory allocation in c if you initialize the strings in Go using `C.String`

> // Go string to C string // The C string is allocated in the C heap
>   using malloc. // It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it
>   to be // freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
>   // if C.free is needed). func C.CString(string) *C.char

You can use c.GoString() to convert the C.String back in to go string. Below is a working code snippet of your sample.

```
package main

/*
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_reverse(char* src, char *dst){
  printf("[c-part] src=%s\n", src);
  int n = strlen(src);
  for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
  {
    dst[i] = src[n - 1 - i];
  }
  dst[n] = 0;
  printf("[c-part] dst=%s\n", dst);
}

void some_text(char* buffer, unsigned long long int *year){
  sscanf("year 2018d", "%s %16llu", buffer, year);
  printf("will return (%s, %16llu)\n", buffer, *year);
}
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"
import "fmt"

func Reverse(a string) (dst string) {
    c_src := C.CString(a)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c_src))
    c_dst := C.CString(dst)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c_dst))
    C.my_reverse(c_src, c_dst)
    return C.GoString(c_dst)
}

func Sometext() (dst string, year int64) {
    c_dst := C.CString("")
    c_year := C.ulonglong(0)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c_dst))
    C.some_text(c_dst, &c_year)
    return C.GoString(c_dst), int64(c_year)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("[gopart] dst=%v\n\n\n", Reverse("Hello World"))

    buf, year := Sometext()
    fmt.Printf("received (%v, %v)\n", buf, year)
}
```

Comment: Both of your `c_dst` are only allocating an empty string (or a single null byte), and then passing them as appropriately sized buffers to the c functions causing buffer overflows. Best case you segfault, but more likely you’re silently currupting the program memory.